# Would here be the right place to ask how to go about creating custom controls?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm new to Programmers, so I'm not too sure the type of questions that are allowed here. I do know that this is more the developmental side of things, so I figured this might be the better place to ask.

I was wondering how I might go about creating a custom control for an MDI app, in C#, specifically a "Task bar" type control to help manage minimised child windows in the MDI Container. Currently they simply sit at the bottom of the screen, and just tile up. Not very appealing to the eye.

So is here a good place to ask for direction on how to do this?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it sounds like the problem you're facing is with usability, rather than maintainability or some other technical attribute, I agree with gnat's comment that ux.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask.